# How to give access to all price books for a cerain user?

Tags: permission-sets, pricebook

I need to give our Finance user, access to all price books (as he needs to edit old opptys)

Is it possible to do that automatically? and not by manually going to each price book, and update the sharing rule?

There is no Profile settings for this afaik

Answer (score 0):

> Pricebook visibility is controlled through the sharing model. Create
>   each price book and then click the share button on it and select the
>   appropriate groups who can use it.

Comment: I know I can do it manually, read the question, looking for an alternate way.

Comment: @Saariko Currently one has to manually share PriceBook record. Although the Pricebookshare object exists, but it is not accessible.